# Java method taking a lot of time to run?

Tags: java, methods

I have this method :

```
public static String captainCrunch(String s){
        int i = 0;
        char hat = ' ';

        while(i < s.length()){
            if(s.charAt(i) >= 'a' && s.charAt(i) <= 'm'){
                hat = (char)(s.charAt(i) + 13);
            }else if(s.charAt(i) > 'm' && s.charAt(i) <= 'z'){
                hat = (char)(s.charAt(i) - 13);
            }else if(s.charAt(i) == ' '){
                hat = ' ';
            }
            s = s + hat;
            i++;
        }
        return s;
    }
```

whenever i run it, it takes too much time like ferver to finish even for small very small strings.... any help?

Comment: you modify both variables that are part of loop condition. It will probably only stop once `i` overflows and gets negative.

Comment: You're adding characters to `s` while you iterate over all characters in `s`.

Comment: You are also always reallocating a new character array in every loop iteration.

Comment: Actually the loop will never stop when you invoke this method because s.length() is always increasing which will probably cause stack overflow or out of memory error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your method is taking so long is because you're adding characters to `s` in every iteration. So whenever the loop checks its condition, it is going to be almost always `true`.

In other words, you're adding 1 to both `s.length()` and `i` every iteration.

That's no good is it? One way to solve this is to put `s.length()` into a variable first so it doesn't get changed when you append a new character to `s`.

```
public static String captainCrunch(String s){
    int i = 0;
    char hat = ' ';

    int length = s.length();
    while(i < length){
        if(s.charAt(i) >= 'a' && s.charAt(i) <= 'm'){
            hat = (char)(s.charAt(i) + 13);
        }else if(s.charAt(i) > 'm' && s.charAt(i) <= 'z'){
            hat = (char)(s.charAt(i) - 13);
        }else if(s.charAt(i) == ' '){
            hat = ' ';
        }
        s = s + hat;
        i++;
    }
    return s;
}
```

But I doubt that you want to it this way because I think your method is trying to obfuscate the string passed in, not appending characters to it. If my guess is correct, you would probably want something like this:

```
public static String captainCrunch(String s){
    int i = 0;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s);

    while(i < s.length()){
        if(s.charAt(i) >= 'a' && s.charAt(i) <= 'm'){
            builder.setCharAt(i, (char)(s.charAt(i) + 13));
        }else if(s.charAt(i) > 'm' && s.charAt(i) <= 'z') {
            builder.setCharAt(i, (char) (s.charAt(i) - 13));
        }
        i++;
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```